# Comparing value between columns and select the top 2nd rating

Tags: sql

rating_reference:

[image: rating_reference]

AutoFind_Rating

[image: AutoFind_Rating]

I need to come out with a query to compare the rating between A,B,C,D,E in the table shown in AutoFind_Rating picture attached. I need to update the rating column with the second best rating after comparing between the columns. If A,B,C,D,E is null then the rating will be 'unrated'. To compare the rating, I will need to refer to the rating reference. AutoFind_Rating has a table that shows what needs to be done. My final goal is to generate the rating after compare A,B,C,D,E and come out with the rating automatically.

Please help to give me ideas how to make it work.
Thanks in advance for your ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: It's seems that you need to translate scores to number, transpose columns to rows, rank the scores descending and choose always number 2. 
What your dbms are?

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio 15 if i get your dbms correctly.